# hidden api key in javascript

Tags: javascript, logic

I need to hide the api key to be able to share my code on github, is it possible to somehow hide this key without needing a backend server and using only js?

my code:

```js
const jokeText = document.querySelector(".joke-text");
const newJokeBtn = document.querySelector(".new-joke-btn");
const categoryForm = document.querySelector(".category-form");
const categorySelect = document.querySelector("#category-select");

const apiKey = "xxxxxx";

function fetchJoke(category = "") {
  let url = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random";

  if (category) {
    url = `https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=${category}`;
  }

  fetch(url)
    .then((repsonse) => repsonse.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const joke = data.value;
      const lang = "en";
      const targetLang = "pt";

      fetch(
        `https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=${apiKey}&q=${joke}&source=${lang}&target=${targetLang}`
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const translatedJoke = data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
          jokeText.innerHTML = translatedJoke;
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}

function fetchCategories() {
  fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.forEach((category) => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = category;
        option.text = category;
        categorySelect.add(option);
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}

newJokeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const category = categorySelect.value;
  fetchJoke(category);
});

categoryForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const category = categorySelect.value;
  fetchJoke(category);
});

fetchCategories();
```

I thought of creating another file to be able to put the key there, and use it, and I would not send this file to github

Comment: That appears to be intended to run in a browser environment, so there's no way to hide the token from end users.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to hiding the API key in your JavaScript code without using a backend server is to use environment variables. Environment variables allow you to store sensitive information like API keys outside of your codebase and access them at runtime.

Here's how you can use environment variables in your code:

1.Create a file called .env in the root directory of your project.

2.In the .env file, add a variable called REACT_APP_API_KEY (assuming you're using React) and set its value to your API key. For example:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=xxxxxx
```

Note: Make sure to replace xxxxxx with your actual API key.

3.In your JavaScript code, you can access the environment variable using process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY. For example:

```
const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
```

This will replace the apiKey variable with the value of the REACT_APP_API_KEY environment variable at runtime.

Note: You may need to restart your development server for the changes to take effect.

Make sure to add .env to your .gitignore file to prevent it from being committed to your repository.

Note: This approach does not completely hide your API key, as it is still visible in the browser's network tab. If you need to completely hide your API key, you'll need to use a backend server to make the API requests on behalf of your client-side code.

Comment: I'm not using framework in this application, the intention is to do this without using framework